# Pass login parameters to scan with owasp zap on docker command

Tags: docker, owasp, zap

I'm trying to execute a command to attack an application with login but I dont know how to pass my user and password to the url.

The login sends a post with user and password to verify if exist.

command to atack.

docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk/:rw -t owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-baseline.py -t http://172.31.95.32:8080/myapp/login -g gen.conf -r testreport.html authMethodName : formBasedAuthentication authMethodConfigParams :loginUrl=http://172.31.95.32:8080/myapp/login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI.

I had to use ictu/zap2docker-weekly image to accomplish this goal.

here is the repo with some examples.

https://github.com/ICTU/zap-baseline

Answer (score 2):

You'd be best off running ZAP in gui mode and sorting out your Context config, which you can export. You can then import and re-use your context within whatever CI or CD process(es) you need.

zap-baseline.py is meant to do exactly what it's name implies. Provide a shallow (passive only) assessment of your app/service.

Further details about ZAP Baseline Scan are available here:

- https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/ZAP-Baseline-Scan
- https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2017/01/25/setting-a-baseline-for-web-security-controls/

Comment: +1 for that. FYI I covered using authentication with Docker in a DevSecCon talk last year: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vVnMh6AUkk&index=14&list=PLEBitBW-Hlsv8cEIUntAO8st2UGhmrjUB&t=1890s